# Whats the meaning of the model default params?

Tags: python, django

When I read a project, there I saw the params for create the field:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('标题', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField('描述')
    completed = models.BooleanField('是否完成', default=False)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('创建时间', auto_now_add=True)
```

Such as: `title = models.CharField('标题', max_length=100)`

I don't understand the `标题` here has what function.

Comment: Can you paste question in English ?

Comment: Any reason you didn't look at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names)?

Comment: @SandeepLade - The question *is* in english, the contents of the strings are irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of a [`Field`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L134) in django is the verbose name

> A human-readable name for the field. If the verbose name isn’t given, Django will automatically create it using the field’s attribute name, converting underscores to spaces

Answer (score 0):

it's the field name displayed in the admin panel forms or if you use ModelForm for you website forms

Answer (score 0):

You will have couple of fields , one default value for that model column , one max length of that model column , alias name for that model column , and if that column is primary that will also be there